# How can Convert DataRowView To DataRow in C#

Tags: c#

I want to use Drag Drop But i don't know How to drag information from a DataGridView control to DataGridView or ListBox ?

i got a link
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/DataGridView_Drag-n-Drop.aspx

Comment: there is no foreach in the code you posted. The error is elsewhere...

Answer (score 51):

DataRowView.Row should contain the DataRow displayed in the view.

Answer (score 10):

A `DataRowView` is not a `DataRow`, and isn't convertible to a DataRow. But, you can access the corresponding DataRow using the `Row` property.

Answer (score 2):

here i've got the solution using the narrow casting

The name of the combobox in this example is CBTables

```
 DataRowView DRV = (DataRowView)CBTables.SelectedItem;
 DataRow DR = (DataRow) DRV.Row;
```