# Why does repeater return DataRowView instead of DataRow?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable("select * from AccountTypes");

    repeater.DataSource = dt;
    repeater.DataBind();
}

private void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item) {
        return;
    }

    var row = (DataRow)e.Item.DataItem;
}
```

It throws exception that "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'."

DataRow is an element of DataTable, but why does e.Item.DataItem become DataRowView?

Can anyone find a MSDN documentation mentioning this?

Comment: I am not sure why the thing is doing what it does, perhaps because repeater produces `DataRowView` objects. Obviously, using `var row = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;` will fix this problem.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting DataRowView - which is a custom version of DataRow, but you can use it as DataRow as this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089147/a-way-to-get-a-datarow-from-a-datarowview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is defined by the DataTable class. Unlike a typical collection class, DataTable implements [IListSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of IEnumerable. The IListSource interface allows a class to "customize" the data provided to data-binding controls like Repeater.

[DataTable's IListSource implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,2928) returns [DefaultView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview(v=vs.110).aspx), so

```
repeater.DataSource = dt;
```

is actually equivalent to

```
repeater.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

The type of DefaultView is [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a DataRowView collection. And that's why your data items are DataRowView objects.

Answer (score 2):

`DataRowView` **encapsulates** a `DataRow`, adding binding functionality that is useful in the context of web controls (like Repeaters).

If you want to interact with the underlying Row, just use the `Row` property, like this:

```
var row = e.Item.DataItem.Row;
```

This is a possible duplicate of [How can Convert DataRowView To DataRow in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179856/how-can-convert-datarowview-to-datarow-in-c-sharp).

Comment: I'm not asking HOW, I'm asking WHY

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable("select * from AccountTypes");

    repeater.DataSource = dt;
    repeater.DataBind();
}

private void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item) {
        return;
    }

    var row = e.Item.DataItem;
}
```